# Do an LDAP Password Modify Extended Operation using PHP?

Tags: php, ldap

Using PHP, is it possible to do an LDAP Password Modify Extended Operation, as specified in [RFC 3062](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3062.txt)? The password hashing scheme in the LDAP directory I am working with may change periodically, so it is my understanding that I can't hash a new password according to a specific scheme, e.g., {SHA}, I need to use an Extended Operation instead and let the directory do the hashing. Is that correct? The help page for [ldap_set_option](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-set-option.php) suggests that it might be possible, but I sure can't find any example code anywhere on the web. Maybe I'm just losing my Google-fu. TIA

Answer (score 1):

LDAP clients must never transmit pre-encoded passwords to the directory server - passwords must always be transmitted in the clear over a secure connection because modern, professional-quality directory servers can perform password quality checks and password history checks only when presented with a clear-text password.

If PHP supports extended operations and extended responses, then the password modify extended operation (which requires the existing password and can generate a password if no new password is supplied) is supported. I am no PHP expert, but I believe that set_option can be used for controls (which are attached to an operation), but I do not know if PHP supports LDAP extended operations.

Comment: Specifically, for example, OpenLDAP's [password policy overlay](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html) can pass the clear text along to a password checker like cracklib.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone stumbling across this question: In PHP > 7.0, it is indeed possible to perform an LDAP Extended Operation. For general Info about ExOps in PHP see [the PHP reference](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ldap-exop.php).

There is also a function specifically for the password change operation (also taken from the [PHP reference](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ldap-exop-passwd.php)):

```php
ldap_exop_passwd($ds, "uid=youruser,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com", "oldpasswd", "secureNewPassword");
```

Where `$ds` is an LDAP link identifier, returned by `ldap_connect()`.

Answer (score -2):

If you're handling the encryption of the password on your side, then yes you can hash it to what encryption method you want.

For MD5:
$pass_ldap = '{MD5}' . base64_encode(pack('H*', md5($pass)));

For SHA-1:
$pass_ldap = '{SHA}' . base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($pass)));

You would then use [ldap_modify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-modify.php) to update an existing users password or [ldap_add](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-add.php) to add a new user with the encrypted password.

I have done this and I think the LDAP server uses the "{}" value to determine what format is being used.

Comment: -1. Not an answer. Doesn't address the Extended Operation requirement.

Comment: Right, I am not handling the password hashing. I believe the directory needs to do it, since the hashing method may vary over time.